# how to install django-sphinx-autodoc

Tags: django, python-sphinx, django-sphinx

i have found this django apps `django-sphinx-autodoc` in http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-autodoc ...

I can't find the docs on how to install it

do anyone knows how to install this app?

Comment: Do you have [Python Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) installed? What OS are you using?

Comment: yes i have, i am using ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's package repositories don't have django-sphinx-autodoc, so you will have to install it yourself.

If you do have `pip` or `distribute` installed, you can use those to install anything from PyPi.

`distribute` gives you the command `easy_install`, which acts as a kind of package manager for Python. `pip` is the same thing, with additional functionality.

For you, you can install with:

```
sudo easy_install django-python-autodoc
```

If you have pip, you can do this:

```
sudo pip install django-python-autodoc
```